# Python 3, Permutation , combination

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, permutation

My problem is:

Write code that prints out all possible combination for x,y,z so that they equal the input value of the total sum. `x,y,z = integer`:

```
x*500 + y*300 + z*400 = total sum
```

but it didn't print out all possible answers. Any suggestion on how to tackle this problem? anything would help.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure how that answer helped, but just to check: integer typically includes negative numbers and you're not checking those; did you mean to only constrain to positive (or non-negative if you wanted to include 0)  (I expect this needs to be limited to non-negative only as otherwise there would be an infinite number of answers if there are any)

Comment: @Foon yes they need to be >0

Comment: @Baller You made a major edit to this question that completely changed what you are asking. Please do not do that. Instead, if one of the answers on this question helped you, you should accept it. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sort of a backtracking algorithm will help out here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

```
public void generatePossiblities(int xVal, int yVal, int zVal, int sum){
   if((xVal + yVal + zVal) == sum){
       print(xVal, yVal, zVal);
       return;
   }

   if((xVal + yVal + zVal) > sum){
       return;
   }


   for(int i = 2; i < sum; i++){
      generatePossiblities(xVal*i, yVal, zVal, sum)
      generatePossiblities(xVal, yVal*i, zVal, sum)
      generatePossiblities(xVal, yVal, zVal*i, sum)
   }
}
```

Just to set a Java Example, as I do not use Python on regular basis. Hope this helps out.